# Attempting to port XTea Encryption Algorithm from C to Python

Tags: python, c, encryption

I'm having trouble translating some C Code into Python. I have tried my best to simulate the nature of integer overflow from C, but have so far been unsuccessful. If anybody has some insight, that would be greatly appreciated as I'm new to python. Encryption & decryption is as follows:

```
iterations = 32
delta = 0x9e3779b9
xTeaKey = [<some int32>, <some int32>, <some int32>, <some int32>]

def int_overflow(val):
    maxint = 2147483647

    if not -maxint-1 <= val <= maxint:
        val = (val + (maxint + 1)) % (2 * (maxint + 1)) - maxint - 1

    if not -maxint-1 <= val <= maxint:
        print "AAAAAH"

    return val

def xTeaShuffle(x, sum, sumOffset) :
    e1 = (x << 4) & 0xffffffff
    e2 = x >> 5
    e3 = e1 ^ e2
    e4 = int_overflow(e3 + x)

    e5a = int_overflow(sum + xTeaKey[(sum & 0x03)]);
    e5b = int_overflow(sum + xTeaKey[((sum >> 11) & 0x03)]);
    e5 = e5b if sumOffset else e5a

    result = e4 ^ e5

    return result

def xTeaEncode(data, length) :
    i = 0

    while i < length:
        sum = 0
        x1 = (data[i] << 16) + data[i + 1]
        x2 = (data[i + 2] << 16) + data[i + 3]

        iter = iterations

        while iter > 0 :
            x1 = int_overflow(x1 + xTeaShuffle(x2, sum, False))
            sum = int_overflow(sum + delta);
            x2 = int_overflow(x2 + xTeaShuffle(x1, sum, True))
            iter -= 1

        data[i] = (x1 >> 16) & 0xffff
        data[i + 1] = x1 & 0xffff
        data[i + 2] = (x2 >> 16) & 0xffff
        data[i + 3] = x2 & 0xffff

        i += 4

    return

def xTeaDecode(data, length) :
    i = 0

    while i < length:
        sum = int_overflow(delta * iterations)
        x1 = (data[i] << 16) + data[i + 1]
        x2 = (data[i + 2] << 16) + data[i + 3]

        while (sum != 0) :
            x2 = int_overflow(x2 - xTeaShuffle(x1, sum, True))
            sum = int_overflow(sum - delta)
            x1 = int_overflow(x1 - xTeaShuffle(x2, sum, False))

        data[i] = (x1 >> 16) & 0xffff
        data[i + 1] = x1 & 0xffff
        data[i + 2] = (x2 >> 16) & 0xffff
        data[i + 3] = x2 & 0xffff

        i += 4

    return
```

And the original C Code

```
DllExport void _stdcall XTEAEncode16(unsigned short *data, unsigned char dataLength) 
{
    unsigned char i = 0;
    int x1;
    int x2;
    int sum;
    unsigned char iterationCount;

    while (i < dataLength) 
    {
        sum = 0;
        x1 = ((unsigned int)data[i] << 16) + (unsigned int)data[i+1];
        x2 = ((unsigned int)data[i+2] << 16) + (unsigned int)data[i+3];
        iterationCount = NUM_ITERATIONS;

        while (iterationCount > 0) 
        {
            x1 += (((x2 << 4) ^ (x2 >> 5)) + x2) ^ (sum + XTEAKey[(sum & 0x03)]);
            sum += DELTA;
            x2 += (((x1 << 4) ^ (x1 >> 5)) + x1) ^ (sum + XTEAKey[((sum >> 11) & 0x03)]);
            iterationCount--;
        }
        data[i]   = (unsigned short)((unsigned int)x1>>16);     /* take upper half as an int*/
        data[i+1] = (unsigned short)(unsigned int)x1;           /* take lower half */
        data[i+2] = (unsigned short)((unsigned int)x2>>16);     /* take upper half as an int*/
        data[i+3] = (unsigned short)(unsigned int)x2;           /* take lower half */

        i += 4;
    }
}

/**
 * Decodes (deciphers) data.
 * Note that data length must be a multiple of 4 words (64 bit). 
 *//* *< 16-bit data array *//* *< length of data array */
DllExport void _stdcall  XTEADecode16(unsigned short* data, unsigned char dataLength ) 
{
    unsigned char i = 0;
    int x1;
    int x2;
    int sum;
    unsigned char iterations;

    iterations = NUM_ITERATIONS;

    while (i < dataLength) 
    {
        sum = DELTA * iterations;
        x1 = ((unsigned int)data[i] << 16) + (unsigned int)data[i+1];
        x2 = ((unsigned int)data[i+2] << 16) + (unsigned int)data[i+3];

        while (sum != 0) 
        {
            x2 -= (((x1 << 4) ^ (x1 >> 5)) + x1) ^ (sum + XTEAKey[((sum >> 11) & 0x03)]);
            sum -= DELTA;
            x1 -= (((x2 << 4) ^ (x2 >> 5)) + x2) ^ (sum + XTEAKey[(sum & 0x03)]);
        }
        data[i]   = (unsigned short)((unsigned int)x1 >> 16);   /* take upper half as an int*/
        data[i+1] = (unsigned short)((unsigned int)x1);         /* take lower half */
        data[i+2] = (unsigned short)((unsigned int)x2 >> 16);   /* take upper half as an int*/
        data[i+3] = (unsigned short)((unsigned int)x2);         /* take lower half */

        i += 4;
    }
}
```

From my experiments, Encryption seems to be ok, but I can never decrypt to the correct value. Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it!!! Here's the gotcha:

When bit-shifting to the right (and depending on the implementation), the bits may be filled with either 0 or 1, depending on the leftmost bit. This is to preserve the sign of a two's compliment binary number. So when simulating a shift on a c integer, if we don't emulate the sign, we must pad the left with 1's if that was the left-most bit.